# php code is displayed as plain text within form fields

Tags: contact-form, php

I want to implement a contact form, but browser displays php code as plain text. Here is the code:

```
<div id="main-container">

    <div id="form-container">
    <h1>Fancy Contact Form</h1>
    <h2>Drop us a line and we will get back to you</h2>

    <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <td width="15%"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
          <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>" /></td>
          <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
          <td><select name="subject" id="subject">
            <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
            <option value="Question">Question</option>
            <option value="Business proposal">Business proposal</option>
            <option value="Advertisement">Advertising</option>
            <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
          </select>          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><label for="message">Message</label></td>
          <td><textarea name="message" id="message" class="validate[required]" cols="35" rows="5"><?=$_SESSION['post']['message']?></textarea></td>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="captcha"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="captcha" id="captcha" /></td>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
          <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" />

          <?=$str?>          <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
      <?=$success?>
    </div>
    <div class="tutorial-info"> 
    This is a Tutorialzine demo. View the <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/">original tutorial</a>, or download the <a href="demo.zip">demo files</a>.    </div>

</div>
```

So, I get these

```
<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>
<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>
<?=$_SESSION['post']['message']?>
```

displayed inside form fields as they are, as plain text. What am doing wrong? Pls, help.

Comment: Is your HTML part of a PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some server, you can't use `<?=`, so you must use this :

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['name']; ?>
```

Or simply enable short tags in php.ini

Comment: I got three same answers that helped me, but you are the fastest ,  RelevantUsername :). I changed  "<?=" into "<?php echo" and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have support for [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) enabled on your php.ini configuration? That might be it.

Answer (score 1):

Before PHP 5.4.0, shorthand statements are affected by `short_open_tag` configuration. You may want to check that. Note, it is not recommended to use these shorthand statements and to just echo your values. It produces more robust and portable code.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 0):

Short tags are probably disabled in PHP.ini and you should not use them anyway

Change`<?=`
To

```
<?php echo
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['name']; ?>"
```

and second

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['email'] ; ?>"
```

and third

```
 <?php echo $_SESSION['post']['message'] ; ?>
```

and so on